# How to point a domain into another website's page?

Tags: nginx, dns

For example, I have a website under the domain `example.com`. In that site, I have a page like this `example.com/hello`. Now I need to point my second domain `hello.com` to that page `example.com/hello`. It should not be a re-direct. The visitor should stay in `hello.com` but see the content from the page `example.com/hello`. Is this possible? Can we do it in dns or in nginx?

The access log after using proxy pass :

```
123.231.120.120 - - [10/Mar/2016:19:53:18 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1598 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
123.231.120.120 - - [10/Mar/2016:19:53:18 +0530] "GET /a4e1020a9f19bd46f895c136e8e9ecb839666e7b.js?meteor_js_resource=true HTTP/1.1" 404 44 "http://swimamerica.lk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.$
123.231.120.120 - - [10/Mar/2016:19:53:18 +0530] "GET /9b342ac50483cb063b76a0b64df1e2d913a82675.css?meteor_css_resource=true HTTP/1.1" 200 73 "http://swimamerica.lk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.262$
123.231.120.120 - - [10/Mar/2016:19:53:18 +0530] "GET /images/favicons/favicon-16x16.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1556 "http://swimamerica.lk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
123.231.120.120 - - [10/Mar/2016:19:53:19 +0530] "GET /images/favicons/favicon-96x96.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1556 "http://swimamerica.lk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
123.231.120.120 - - [10/Mar/2016:19:53:19 +0530] "GET /images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1556 "http://swimamerica.lk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
123.231.120.120 - - [10/Mar/2016:19:53:19 +0530] "GET /images/favicons/android-icon-192x192.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1556 "http://swimamerica.lk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: if `hello` is a dir why won't you setup the server for that domain?

Comment: Hello is a page... Not a simple html site which have an index in which case we can point the domain. It's a site built with meteor :-(

Comment: I think you should just point to the same place as example.com and write rewrite rules that would rewrite url `hello.com/(.*)` to `./hello/$1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `proxy_pass` [directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass). Just create a new server associated with the domain `hello.com` and then for `location = /` set `proxy_pass` equals to `http://example.com/hello`:

```
server {
    server_name hello.com;
    # ...
    location = / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com/hello/;
    }

    # serve static content (ugly way)
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|rss|txt)$ {
        proxy_pass http://example.com/hello/$uri$is_args$args;
    }

    # serve static content (better way, 
    # but requires collection all assets under the common root)
    location ~ /static/ {
        proxy_pass http://example.com/static/;
    }
}
```

**UPD:** Here is an exact solution for your situation:

```
server {
    server_name swimamerica.lk;

    location = / {
        proxy_pass http://killerwhales.lk/swimamerica;
    }

    # serve static content (ugly way) - added woff and woff2 extentions
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|rss|txt|woff|woff2)$ {
        proxy_pass http://killerwhales.lk$uri$is_args$args;
    }

    # added location for web sockets
    location ~* sockjs {
        proxy_pass http://killerwhales.lk$uri$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but one issue... The site now try to load all the resource (js, css, image, etc) as hello domain. Example : `hello.com/main.js` but they are under `example.com/main.js`. So, the site fails to load.

Comment: What is in nginx access/error logs? And how is browser network console looks like?

Comment: There's no error in the error log. I just added the access log :-)

Comment: not to be mean, but that's the worst idea I ever heard of :-) isn't it better to use rewrite rules?

Comment: @THpubs please read [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html).

Comment: @FlashThunder Sorry it's a bit unclear to me on how to do this. Do I have to write re-write rules to each and every resource (js, images, css, etc) in the domain?

Comment: @THpubs, I've updated my answer. Now it includes an adapted solution for your task.

Comment: @Ostrovski Great! Thanks a lot man! This really helped! When I applied it, there were no errors but it loaded the root of killerwhales.lk... not killerwhales.lk/swimamerica as I wanted. So, I set a custom header and in my app's router, watch for the custom header, if it match, load the swimamerica route at the root! It worked!

Answer (score -2):

Use the `proxy_pass` directive. Just create a new server associated with the domain `hello.com` and then for `location = /` set `proxy_pass` equal to `http://domain.com/hello`:

```
server {
    server_name hello.com;
    # ...
    location = / {
        proxy_pass http://domain.com/hello/;
    }

    # serve static content (ugly way)
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|rss|txt)$ {
        proxy_pass http://domain.com/hello/$uri$is_args$args;
    }

    # serve static content (better way, 
    # but requires collection all assets under the common root)
    location ~ /static/ {
        proxy_pass http://domain.com/static/;
    }
}
```